# Is there a way where I make a Salesforce report on users/agents logged into Omni-Channel (WhatsApp)?

Tags: omnichannel, messagingsession, omni-supervisor

I am new to Omni-Channel. I am looking to create a report on the following fields for each agents to get logged in details for yesterday into Salesforce.

- Name
- Logged in time and date
- Logged out time and date.

I am working on creating a report for each user capacity based on these.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a report on the [UserServicePresence](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_userservicepresence.htm) object, which stores information regarding each Agent's presence status, duration, and dates.

Below is an example query that you can run to see the data provided:

```
SELECT Id, ServicePresenceStatus.MasterLabel, User.Name, StatusStartDate, StatusEndDate, StatusDuration FROM UserServicePresence
```

Comment: I am looking to make  a salesforce report into system itself. Through this I think it is not possible to make report on daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this salesforce app exchange product to check the agent performance. It comes with variety of reports. It's a free product.
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G0yalUAB